# drawInRect behavior with UIView rotation transform

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, cgaffinetransform

I have a problem understanding how the parameter passed to the drawInRect method is defined when a rotation transformation is performed on a UIView.

To give an example I have a UIView which I rotated with an angle of 307 degree.
In the drawInRect method I log the following:
self.frame: {{103.932, 273.254}, {64.3007, 84.3374}}
rect (the variable passed as parameter:{{0, 0.102913}, {18, 89}}

The problem is that according to the documentation I should not draw outside of rect, but considering what I should draw, there is no way my images will fit there.

Can anyone explain to me how I am supposed to use drawInRect in the case my UIView is rotated ?

---

To give more detail about my problem, here is what I do:

I have a scrollview with a contentView inside (subclassed). I add my UIViews in the content view.

The views in question are composed of a handler image (bottom left) and the main image (top right). Users are supposed to grab the view by pressing the handler but that's not the point.

The drawInRect method of the UIView contains the following:

```
[_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(handlerSize.width, 0, _image.size.width, _image.size.height)];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(kHandPickerWidth/self.scrollViewScale, kHandPickerHeight/self.scrollViewScale);
[_handPickerImage drawInRect:(0, _image.size.height, size.width, size.height)];
```

The UIViews objects are added at viewWillAppear in the content view doing the following:

first instanciate,

then addSubview:

then I set the scrollViewScale parameter,

then I set the frame parameter (according to the top right image displayed (which may vary)

then I rotate the UIView.

Starting from line three, the code is executed from the

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

to make sure every variable is set properly when displayed is needed.

The line defining the size variable is to adjust the marker's size no mater the zoomScale value of the scroll view.

Comment: Please just edit your question if you want to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem:

I was setting the frame parameter multiple times with some CGAffineTransformation defined which is not supposed to be done.

Now each time I need to reset the frame I reset the affine transform, change the frame and set the back the affine transform.

Everything works as supposed to this way.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just draw as you would normally, and the painting will be rotated by iOS for you. You can get this transformation information if you would want to.

You need to get a reference to the currect graphics context:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Then query the transformation matrix directly:

```
CGAffineTransform tf = CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
NSLog(@"current ctm: %@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(tf));
```

or better, get the transfrom from your drawing function to the device:

```
CGAffineTransform tf = CGContextGetUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform(ctx);
NSLog(@"user->device transform: %@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(tf));
```

And in `drawRect:` you should not rely too much on the passed `CGRect`, because it serves mostly as a hint to what piece of the view needs updating. (e.g. because you called `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` on it). To get the actual bounds where your view lives in, use `self.bounds`.

Drawing outside of the `CGRect` is no real problem, but will only hurt performance a little.

**edit**
ps. to clarify: `self.frame` is the frame of your view in the parent view coordinate system. It changes if you move, rotate or otherwise transform the view. `self.bounds` is the frame of your view in its own coordinate system, and (therefore) remains constant under changes of position or transformations.

Comment: I tried to log self.bounds, it gives values similar to the rect variable so It doesn't help to use it either. I tried to drawmy images as I want, ignoring the rect parameter but my images are truncated. Maybe there is a UIView parameter that I do not set properly.

Comment: does it work without the rotation of 307 degrees? Or are you trying to solve all problem in one go?

Comment: Yes, without rotation it works fine. I have two images drawn on my UIView, one on the top right corner and the other on the bottom left corner.

Comment: @Alexandre: ok, could you show some code? `-drawRect:` and possibly the lines where you apply the rotation?

Comment: Hi, you can check the answer below where I give details about my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexandre: I'm sorry, this is all a bit too vague to help you with. Try rotating just 5 degrees (`5*M_PI/180`) and see what happens. Then gradually increase the angle until you see when/how the view disappears as you approach 307 degrees.